# Calculate PDF content height in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have to render PDF file on a `UIWebView`, but i am unable to calculate the actual height of the `PDF`, since i am using `UITableView` so i need to set the cell height which has UIWebView.

I am able to calculate the HTML content using below code.

```
    CGRect frame = newsWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    frame.size.height = newsWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;  // Get the corresponding height from the webView's embedded scrollView.
    webViewHeight =frame.size.height ;
```

Is there any ways to calculate PDF content hieght??

Answer (score 1):

you can Try this set sizeToFit property and again set Frame of UIWebView in webViewDidFinishLoad

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
       [detailsWebView sizeToFit];
       [detailsWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(detailsWebView.frame.origin.x, detailsWebView.frame.origin.y, 300.0, detailsWebView.frame.size.height)];

}
```

here you can resize webview height according to your PDF content in this method and subsequently resize cell

Answer (score 0):

//Try This code

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{        
    CGFloat height = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
    CGFloat width = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    frame.size.width = width;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: height/width comes back as zero with this method on iOS 9

Comment: @owenfi did you try this NSLog(@"%f",myWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

Comment: after sizeToFit the frame property returns the expected height, but setting a breakpoint and looking at height/width as set in your method are zero.