# App Transport Security issue in iOS 9 and iOS 10

Tags: ios

Apple has announced that `NSAllowArbitraryLoads` will not work soon. Therefore, in iOS 10, I have this in my info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>myAPIdomain</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

This works for my API request and content in UIWebView. However, in iOS9, `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` is not supported and it is recommended to include `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` for iOS 9 support. But I think this will override my `NSExceptionDomains` settings? How can I make HTTP requests for my API and UIWebView work on both iOS 9 and iOS 10 and still following Apple's rule?

**Edit**

For supporting iOS 9 and iOS 10:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>myAPIdomain</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
```

Comment: If you are supporting earlier version than iOS 10 then you need to use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, and yes this will apply on iOS 9 and 10.  You simply need to include in your review notes why you need `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`  If you have specific domains where you know https will work, you can add an exception for those domains to enable https

Comment: @Paulw11Thanks for your quick reply. This means I just need to add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to my info.plist?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: @Paulw11I have edited the post. I think that on iOS10, the key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` and `NSExceptionDomains` will work. On iOS 9, the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` will work. Am I correct?

Comment: I believe that `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` will override `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` even on ios 10, so ATS will effectively be "off" on iOS 9 and iOS 10 devices

Comment: @Paulw11No. On iOS 10, if I do not set `NSExceptionDomains`, my API domain won't work. That means `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` will take effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

You can use the above condition if you don't want to support https(TLS 1.2). But you have to make sure it will be a temporary fix. From earlier 2017 Apple make https (TLS 1.2) as mandatory

Comment: This is not true.  You will be able to continue to use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` but you need to explain why it is required

Comment: I know Apple will make strict use of `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` from 2017. But I want to support iOS 9 also. Seems `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` must be needed for supporting iOS 9.

Comment: Plus there are many devices, such as embedded/IoT devices, that will never support TLS